# SetCurrentConsoleFontEx() doesn't work with custom installed fonts

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, visual-c++

I have a custom font installed on my environment (Pixel Operator Mono) and I'm developing some console application which needs this font. This is my function:

```
void set_font() {
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 27;
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Pixel Operator Mono");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
}
```

Using "Consolas", "Courier New" or even "MS Gothic" seems to work fine. But "Pixel Operator Mono" doesn't. This font is displayed on my CMD properties and I can even set as default font. But why exactly I can't change this way? I already checked and SetCurrentConsoleFontEx is returning success.

**Edit 1:**
I use this function to get the errors as strings. But debugging I can see `errorMessageId` always gets 0. I call this function right after `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()` call.

```
std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //Get the error message, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if(errorMessageID == 0)
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: [If the function fails, the return value is zero. **To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`**.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex)

Comment: The function is returning 1 and GetLastError is returning 0. Which should mean no errors.

Comment: As much as we'd like to take your word for it, 9 out of 10 developers get error reporting wrong. Show your error handling code.

Comment: Edited the post to add the handling stuff

Comment: The error handling code is *still* missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that the custom font and other normal fonts are in the same code page (usually 437), which can be set through [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp).

Next, for the setting of [`FontFamily`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wmf/9a632766-1f1c-4e2b-b1a4-f5b1a45f99ad), try to modify to `FF_MODERN << 4 | TMPF_VECTOR | TMPF_TRUETYPE` for testing.

Here is the Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void set_font() {
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
    SetConsoleOutputCP(437);
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 27;
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_MODERN << 4 | TMPF_VECTOR | TMPF_TRUETYPE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Pixel Operator Mono");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    set_font();

    return 0;
}
```